# Does the shortest path mining algorithm of Neo4j require the relationship between nodes to be in the same direction

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo, graph-data-science

[image]

Please take a look at the picture.

I wanted to use Yen's Algorithm Shortest Path from Neo4j Graph Data Science to dig the Shortest Path between A and F, but nothing came back.

The following code:

```
MATCH (source:Location{name: ‘A’}), (target:Location{name: ‘F’})
CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream(‘myGraph’, {
sourceNode: source,
targetNode: target
})
YIELD index, sourceNode, targetNode,nodeIds,path
RETURN
index,
gds.util.asNode(sourceNode).name AS sourceNodeName,
gds.util.asNode(targetNode).name AS targetNodeName,
[nodeId IN nodeIds | gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name] AS nodeNames,
nodes(path) as path
ORDER BY index
```

Does the relation between A and F need to be in the same direction.

If I just want to look at the shortest distance between A and F, regardless of the direction and weight of relation, what should I do.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

On Neo4j 4.4 there is an option to use [`shortestPath`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/), in which you can define the direction or use both directions like this:

```
MATCH (source:Location{name: ‘A’}), (target:Location{name: ‘F’})
p = shortestPath((source)-[*]-(target))
RETURN p
```

Comment: thanks,If I want to use THE GDS science library of Neo4j to realize the shortest path mining, do I have to keep the direction of Relation consistent

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is yes